# Template wrapper for const and non const member functions of arbitrary classes

Tags: c++, templates, constants, pointer-to-member

I want to have a templated class (wrapper), which can take all possible classes (T) and do stuff (here evaluate) with the member functions of these classes (function).

I found similar requests, which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090109/non-type-template-function-pointer-to-const-member-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926482/const-and-non-const-template-specialization), but neither could satisfy the two conditions below.

Conditions:

1. Both, a pointer to the instance of the class ( T * ptr) and a pointer to the member function (function) must be accessible within the wrapper class.
2. The wrapper class shall work with both, const and non-const member functions.

Here a code that works only for non-const:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

template< class T, double (T::*fck) (double) >
struct Wrapper
{
  Wrapper( T * ptrT);

  double evaluate( double );

protected:

  T * myPtrT;
};


template< class T, double (T::*fck) (double) >
Wrapper<T, fck>::Wrapper( T * ptrT) : myPtrT(ptrT) {}


template< class T, double (T::*fck) (double) >
double Wrapper<T, fck>::evaluate( double s )
{ return (myPtrT->*fck)(s); }


struct kernel
{
  double gauss( double s )
  {
    return exp(-0.5*s*s);
  }
};

int main()
{
  kernel G;

  Wrapper<kernel, &kernel::gauss> myKernel ( &G );

  std::cout<< myKernel.evaluate(0.0) <<std::endl;
  std::cout<< myKernel.evaluate(0.3) <<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the `Wrapper` class strictly necessary?  It looks like you're trying to create a generic evaluation mechanism for classes that provide functions with a standard signature: `double f(double)`.  This is easily solved using `std::function` (C++11) or `boost::function` (C++03).

Using `boost::function` and `boost::bind` in C++03:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

struct kernel
{
  double gauss( double s )
  {
    return exp(-0.5*s*s);
  }
};

int main()
{
    kernel G;

    typedef boost::function<double (double)> MyWrapper;

    MyWrapper w( boost::bind(&kernel::gauss, G, _1) );
    std::cout << w(0.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << w(0.3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All programming problems can be solved by another level of abstraction, except too many levels of abstraction.

```
template< class T, class Op >
struct Wrapper
{
  Wrapper():t(nullptr){}
  Wrapper( T* ptrT ):t(ptrT){}
  Wrapper( Wrapper const& ) = default;
  Wrapper& operator=( Wrapper const& ) = default;

  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args) const->decltype( Op{}(std::declval<T*>(),std::declval<Args>()...)) {
    return Op{}(t, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  T* t;
};

template< class T, bool isConst, class Sig >
struct MemberFunc;
template< class T, class R, class... Args >
struct MemberFunc<T, false, R(Args...) > {
  template< R(T::*func)(Args...) >
  struct type {
    template<class... Ts>
    R operator()(T* t, Ts&&...ts) const {
      return (t->*func)(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
  };
};
template< class T, class R, class... Args >
struct MemberFunc<T, true, R(Args...) > {
  template< R(T::*func)(Args...) const >
  struct type {
    template<class... Ts>
    R operator()(T const* t, Ts&&...ts) const {
      return (t->*func)(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
  };
};

struct kernel
{
  double gauss( double s )
  {
    return exp(-0.5*s*s);
  }
};

int main()
{
  kernel G;

  Wrapper<kernel, MemberFunc<kernel, false, double(double)>::type<&kernel::gauss>> myKernel(&G);

  std::cout<< myKernel(0.0) <<std::endl;
  std::cout<< myKernel(0.3) <<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/GuKTyR)

`MemberFunc::type` is basically a compile-time evaluated `std::mem_fun`.

`Wrapper` now takes a stateless functor as its second argument, which it perfect forwards into.  `MemberFunc<...>::type<...>` builds such a stateless functor wrapping a member function.

I took the liberty of making it work with arbitrary function signatures, and getting rid of `.evaluate` -- we have an invokation operator, if we have an instance whose job it is to be invoked, just invoke it.

Of course, this can also be done with a lambda:

```
auto myKernel = [G](double s)->double { return G->gauss( s ); };
```

but the type of `myKernel` prevents it from being easily stored and returned in some cases without type-erasing it.  Type-erasing it adds runtime indirection, which has runtime costs.

You should still try the type-erased `std::function` solution first, and see if it has performance costs, as the code is much, much simpler and easier to read.